# Invalid colum name

Tags: sql-server

O SQL Server está me apresentando o seguinte aviso:
"Invalid column name", sendo que o nome da coluna não tem nada demais..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Com a imagem fica difícil ler. Coloque dados em texto. De preferência dados adicionais que ajudem esclarecer. Talvez seja inválido porque não exista na tabela.

Comment: Simplesmente diz:
Invalid column name 'anoProximaAudiencia'.

Comment: Achei a pergunta vaga, não dá pra entender se é erro em uma query, ou na tabela, enfim, se possível explique melhor.

Comment: Não, o erro é apresentado na própria tabela, quando mando abrir uma listagem da tabela.

Comment: Conseguem enxergar agora?

Comment: O select está apontando para o banco certo? Já me aconteceu algumas vezes de estar rodando a query no master invés do meu banco.

Comment: Vê se algum desses links te ajuda:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260487/sql-server-reports-invalid-column-name-but-the-column-is-present-and-the-quer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636025/invalid-column-name-in-sql-server-management-studio
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840750/invalid-column-name-in-management-studio-but-query-suceeds

Comment: Mas você consegue executar a SQL? Porque isso pode ser só o intelissence mostrando uma informação incorreta

Comment: Não, não funciona uma simples query, usando esse campo, por causa disso.

Comment: Pior que nenhum aviso de erro aparece quando executo uma query via sistema, apenas nada, nenhum resultado aparece.

Comment: Sim @Luis Henrique, o select está apontando para o banco certo.
Mas o problema nem aparece na execução da query...

Comment: @Marcelo Bonifazio, infelizmente, nenhum deles ajudou, até porque são problemas um pouco diferentes do meu.

Comment: Pessoal, consegui.
Tive que pressionar Ctrl + Shift + R e reiniciar o SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

As abas do `SQL Server Management Studio` trabalham com cache local, sendo assim, segundo a documentação, utilize as teclas de atalho <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> para atualizar.

A documentação de atalhos em português pode ser encontrada [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts).